# ObservableCollection и MobileServiceClient

Tags: c#, windows-10, mobile-development, windows-10-mobile, azure-storage

Здравствуйте.
Не могу придумать как добавить **`ObservableCollection`** в таблицу находящийся в облаке **Azure** ....
У меня есть 2 ObservableCollection 
`Fullorder = new ObservableCollection<order>();`
`Nickorder = new ObservableCollection<order>();`
и одноименные таблицы в облаке **Azure**

Раньше я делал так, когда добавлял в таблицу `demomenu` которая находится в AZURE

```
public static MobileServiceClient MobileSerice = new  MobileServiceClient("http://mrcoffeservice.azurewebsites.net");
private MobileServiceCollection<demomenu, demomenu> items;
private async void addbutn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        demomenu item = new demomenu
        {name = "Печенька",
         cost = 150};
        await App.MobileService.GetTable<demomenu>().InsertAsync(item);
    }
```

как видите у меня все называется одинаково и классы и таблиц и коллекции `demomenu`, а теперь у меня у коллекций разные имена `Fullorder`и `Nickorder` и один класс `order`и 2 таблицы
P.S. и заполнял каждый элемент в ручную , а теперь они у меня лежат в коллекциях которые выглядят как раз, как таблицы в Azure, и просто нужно брать элемент коллекии и помешать в таблицу так как у них одна структура

Comment: А вы пробовали `GetTable(string)`, с именем?

Comment: Делал вот так  `foreach (var Collection in App.Nickorder)
            {
                await App.MobileSerice.GetTable("Nickorder").InsertAsync(Collection);
            }` но тогда говорит что не может преобразовать `Collection` в `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject`

Comment: Ну это уже вроде другая проблема? Какого типа в этом случае ваш `Collection`? Скастьте к нужному типу, если что.